# Faster way to get all the intermediate outputs in tf keras

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I want to collect some statistics of the activations of each layer in a network, and I have implemented a version of the idea usually described in answers: get all the outputs you want, create a new graph from the input, and feed again the input. Of course that means I eat a factor two because of reevaluating the graph, plus the overhead of capturing the input just recently used, plus the overhead of statistics being made in a different context. I wonder if there is a faster solution while minimising the modifications to the original model.

My solution currently is as follows. First I capture the input data during the call. Here I can not see how to do it without using an ad-hoc subclass of Model:

```
class MonitoredModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        if  not hasattr(self, "data"):
            self.data = list()
            for dataTensor in inputs:
                self.data.append(tf.Variable(dataTensor, dtype=dataTensor.dtype, trainable=False))
        else:
            for i , dataTensor in enumerate(inputs):
                self.data[i].assign(dataTensor)
        return super().call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    #def train_step(self, data):
    #    print("on train step",self.name,data)
    #    x, y_true, sample_weight = tf.keras.utils.unpack_x_y_sample_weight(data)
```

then in the callback I recover the data in each batch

class LayerStatsCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
def **init**(self, per_step=False, epoch=0, layer_names=None):
self.layer_names = layer_names
self.per_step = per_step
self.step = 0
self.epoch = epoch
self.bad=[]

```
def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
    print("on train begin")
    self._initcounters()

def _initcounters(self):
    self.layer_sums = {}
    self.layer_sumsquares = {}
    self.layer_counts = {}
    
def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
    self.epoch = epoch

def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
    self._end(logs)

def on_test_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
    self.on_batch_end(batch, logs)

def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
    self.step += 1
    names=list()
    outputs=list()
    for i, layer in enumerate(self.model.layers): 
        layer_output = layer.output
        if  _blacklisted(layer)
            continue
        if len(layer_output.shape) > 0:
            names.append(layer.name)
            outputs.append(layer.output)
    keras_func = tf.keras.backend.function(self.model.input, outputs)
    results = keras_func(self.model.data)
    default_mask = _maskFromInput(self.model.data)
    for layer_output, layer_name in zip(results, names):
            layer_output=tf.convert_to_tensor(layer_output)
            layer_sum = tf.reduce_sum(layer_output, axis=(0,1) )
            layer_sumsquares = tf.reduce_sum(layer_output ** 2, axis=(0,1))
            if hasattr(layer,"_keras_mask"):
                mask = layer._keras_mask #not sure if finds any
            else:
                mask= default_mask
            nonzero = tf.math.count_nonzero(mask)  
            layer_count = tf.cast(nonzero,tf.float32)*layer_output.shape[-1]
            if layer_name not in self.layer_sums:
                self.layer_sums[layer_name] = metricSumLayer(ancho=layer_output.shape[-1],name="metrixSumLayer_"+layer_name)
                self.layer_sumsquares[layer_name] = metricSumLayer(ancho=layer_output.shape[-1],name="metrixSqLayer_"+layer_name)
                self.layer_counts[layer_name] = metricSumLayer(ancho=1,name="metrixCntLayer_"+layer_name)
            self.layer_sums[layer_name](layer_sum)
            self.layer_sumsquares[layer_name](layer_sumsquares)
            lcount=tf.expand_dims(layer_count,axis=0)
            self.layer_counts[layer_name](lcount)
    if batch % 10 == 5:
        self._end(logs)
```

I save the stats into an ad-hoc layer because I was having issues with KerasTensor virtual placeholders.

```
class vectorSumMetric(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
    def __init__(self, ancho=1, name=None, **kwargs):
        super(vectorSumMetric, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.acumulator = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros((ancho,)), trainable=False, name="acumulator"+self.name, dtype=tf.float32)
    def update_state(self, newdata, sample_weight=None):
        self.acumulator.assign_add(tf.cast(newdata,tf.float32))
    def result(self):
        return self.acumulator
    def reset_states(self):
        self.acumulator.assign(tf.zeros_like(self.acumulator))


class metricSumLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, ancho=1, name=None, **kwargs):
        super(metricSumLayer, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.metric = vectorSumMetric(ancho, name=name+"_metric")
    def call(self, inputs):
        self.metric.update_state(inputs)
        return self.metric.result()
```

then either periodically of at end of epoch I output my stats for TensorBoard.

```
def _end(self, logs=None, step=None):
    for i,layer in enumerate(self.model.layers):
        if layer.name in self.layer_sums:
            number_of_logits=layer.output.shape[-1]
            layer_sum = self.layer_sums[layer.name].metric.result().numpy()
            layer_sumsquares = self.layer_sumsquares[layer.name].metric.result().numpy()
            layer_count = self.layer_counts[layer.name].metric.result().numpy()
            layer_mean = layer_sum / (1.0+layer_count)
            layer_var = layer_sumsquares / (1.0+layer_count) - layer_mean ** 2
            layer_std = tf.sqrt(layer_var)
            is_near_zero = tf.math.abs(layer_mean) < 1e-5
            percent_near_zero = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(is_near_zero, tf.float32))*tf.cast(number_of_logits,tf.float32)*100.0
            is_var_near_zero = tf.math.abs(layer_var) < 1e-5
            percent_almost_constant = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(is_var_near_zero, tf.float32)) *tf.cast(number_of_logits,tf.float32)*100.0
            tf.summary.scalar(f"{layer.name}/mean", tf.reduce_mean(layer_mean).numpy(), step=self.step)
            tf.summary.scalar(f"{layer.name}/stddev", tf.reduce_mean(layer_std).numpy(), step=self.step)
            tf.summary.scalar(f"{layer.name}/percent_constant", percent_almost_constant.numpy(), step=self.step)
            tf.summary.scalar(f"{layer.name}/percent_zero", percent_near_zero.numpy(), step=self.step)
            tf.summary.flush()
```

I think the main source of delay is the need to capture the input

```
            for i , dataTensor in enumerate(inputs):
                self.data[i].assign(dataTensor)
```

and then reevaluate it

```
    keras_func = tf.keras.backend.function(self.model.input, outputs)
    results = keras_func(self.model.data)
```

I guess this has the advantage of avoiding interference with automatic loss calculations that could accumulate if the original graph is executed two times, but still it seems overkill. I wonder if it is possible to deep inspect the nodes of the graph and insert the proper capture of outputs to make sure they are stored already in the first run.